# ASP.NET RadioButtonList layout not working

Tags: asp.net

No matter what I set on the radiobuttonlist, it still renders are an unordered verticle list.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="myCtrl" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" style="margin-bottom: 0px" >
            < asp:ListItem Text="Add it!" Selected="False" />
            < asp:ListItem Text="No, thank you." Selected="false" />
        < /asp:RadioButtonList >
```

Comment: your code seems to be right......

Comment: Any reason you have RepeatLayout=flow? The default is table.

Comment: becasue the options need to be inline with my text before it. a table will make it go to a new line. Flow wraps the items in SPAN tags. I don't want a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this and it just doesn't work for me either. Must be a bug in ASP.NET i tried asp.net 4 and 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Sitefinity (as I am) it may be due to a Sitefinity-implemented-adapter...

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/general-discussions/add-another-workaround-to-problem.aspx

http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/rendering-radiobuttonlist.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I got this working with ASP.NET 4.0 by including it in a Skin file.

e.g.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList SkinID="HorizontalInlineRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="3" />
```